# wp_link_pages and the_posts_pagination → whats the difference

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

> 1. REQUIRED: The theme doesn't have post pagination code in it. Use
>    posts_nav_link() or paginate_links() or the_posts_pagination() or
>    the_posts_navigation() or next_posts_link() and
>    previous_posts_link() to add post pagination.
> 2. REQUIRED: Could not find wp_link_pages. See: wp_link_pages

above are theme-check plugin warning.

On the basis of Implementation, what is the difference between the two.

Please validate my understanding →

## 1 is for front/homepage in WordPress

## 2 is for single posts

Right?

Comment: Yes, 1/ It is for all the pages wich contain multiple post preview (like a /blog/ page), 2/ wp_link_pages is for display page-links for paginated within posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

**1/** It is for all the pages wich contain multiple post preview (like a /blog/ page),

**2/** [wp_link_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) is for display page-links for paginated within posts

Comment: Can you please delete the answer so that I can delete the question?

Comment: @designtocode He was answered correctly. From the doc-block of `wp_link_pages()` said _Displays page links for paginated posts (i.e. including the `<!--nextpage-->`Quicktag one or more times)._ And the doc-block of `the_posts_pagination()` said. _Displays a paginated navigation to next/previous set of posts, when applicable._

Comment: @somethingnow Please don't delete this question, it is useful for the others too. (Upvoted both of you).

Comment: Hi @vee this was posted a few years ago and I must have read the question incorrectly.